# Statement.executeInsert() Return Value

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

Say I have `ProductVersion` `Table`:

```
CREATE TABLE ProductVersion 
(
   Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, 
   PrvVersionName NOT NULL
);
```

And I have this code to do **INSERT** on this table:

```
   SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
   String sql = "INSERT INTO ProductVersion (PrvVersionName) VALUES (?);";

   SQLiteStatement s = database.compileStatement(sql);
   s.bindString(1, data.getVersionName());

   long id = s.executeInsert();
   s.close();
```

My question, is the value returned from `s.executeInsert()` same as if I query using `"SELECT last_insert_rowid();"` after doing this **INSERT**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`executeInsert()` will return the ID of the row inserted

FROM DOCS

[**`SQLiteStatement.executeInsert ()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteStatement#executeinsert)

> Execute this `SQL` statement and return the ID of the row inserted due to this call. The `SQL` statement should be an INSERT for this to be a useful call.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteStatement.html#executeInsert()) for `SQLiteStatement#executeInsert` seems to confirm this:

> Execute this SQL statement and return the ID of the row inserted due to this call. The SQL statement should be an INSERT for this to be a useful call.